# Whats the difference in replicate_wild_do_table and replicate_do_table?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me the exact difference in replicate_wild_do_table and replicate_do_table while creating Slave.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replicate-wild-do-table` allows you to restrict replication statements to databases and tables using `%` and `_` wildcard characters, that is perform pattern matching.

Where `replicate-do-table` uses concrete databases and tables names.

Here's a manual reference: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html)

**UPDATE:**

Seems like you are having trouble with `USE` statement or fully qualified table names (those with database name specified) in your setup. First of all, there are 2 types of binary logging:

- Statement-based
- Row-based

In short, statement-based replication logs every statement that could modify data and row-based logs modified rows.

Here's a manual reference: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-formats.html)

Here's a comparison from the manual: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html)

Those two types imply different behaviour for replication options. The key one here is that for statement-based replication MySQL replicates statements that are performed on default (selected via `USE`) database only.

So the question is: do you need cross-database updates? If so, you can't use `replicate-do-db`, because it restricts replication on database level. In terms of cross-database updates, there is no difference between `replicate-wild-do-table` and `replicate-do-table`.

Comment: I think there is some difference regarding statements which has use database command before execution and some doesn't have use database command..

Comment: Okay. You should've mentioned that in your question. I'll update my answer with some specifics